# I can not configure Intent and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want from the "class gps_Listener" create "Intent" and send parameters in "class LocationChangedReceiver"

my class gps_Listener

```
public class gps_Listener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            send("I found the location");

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void send(String str) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("logGPS");
            intent.putExtra("Message", str);
            sendBroadcast(intent);   //-  without context does not work

        }


    }
```

and class LocationChangedReceiver

```
public class LocationChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I do not know how to do, as you can see there is no "Context"

Comment: Usually class names in java (and thus android) start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a context to your listener when you create it.
So you can use it in your send method:

```
public class gps_Listener implements LocationListener {
    private Context context;

    public gps_Listener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

    public void send(String str) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.your.package.YOUR_ACTION");
        intent.putExtra("Message", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Create it that way:

```
gps_Listener myListener = new gps_Listener(yourContext);
LocationManager myManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myListener);
```

Remember to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest (you could also un/register dynamically):

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.LocationChangedReceiver" android:enabled="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.your.package.YOUR_ACTION"></action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: my BroadcastReceiver can work without context?
For example if I add in the manifest <receiver android:name=".receivers.LocationChangedReceiver">

Comment: @MaxUsanin Yes you can register your receiver in the manifest. But add an intent filter so it can receive only the intents you want. Was that your question? <receiver android:name=".receivers.LocationChangedReceiver" android:enabled="true"><intent-filter><action android:name="yourIntentAction"></action></intent-filter></receiver>

Comment: Yes I would like to know =) We have come to this. Tell me how do I do sendBroadcast (intent);? in this instance

Comment: @MaxUsanin Well, from what I understand, it already is in my answer: call `context.sendBroadcast(intent);` in your `send()` method, with the `context` you give when you create your `gps_Listener`

Comment: No no, I do not know how to do sendBroadcast (intent) - not using "Context" when <receiver android:name=".receivers.LocationChangedReceiver" android:enabled="true"> <intent-filter> <action android: name = "yourIntentAction "> </ action> </ intent-filter> </ receiver>

Comment: @MaxUsanin Does my edit anwser your question? I have to say I do not really understand what you mean when you talk about context for the manifest.

Comment: For pass parameters to the BroadcastReceiver, always need a context?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17484/discussion-between-max-usanin-and-romain-guidoux)